# How to fix Terminal error DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/usr/bin/login) is setuid or setgid?

Tags: terminal, macos

Any time I open a new terminal window (independent of terminal app), the console stderr displays `dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/usr/bin/login) is setuid or setgid` before the first bash prompt.

The start of this error coincided with my install of 10.8.

How can I get rid of that message?

Below is my .bash_profile:

```
export PS1="\u@MBP:\W ->"

##
# Your previous /Users/segiddins/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/segiddins/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2012-04-19_at_21:00:04
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2012-04-19_at_21:00:04: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

Comment: In your home folder `~/` there should be a file called `.bash_profile`. Could you [paste it somewhere](http://paste.debian.net/) and show us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem might be with asepsis (If you have it installed).　http://asepsis.binaryage.com/

Re-install it to make sure that it's up-to-date. And then Download the Command Line Tools from XCode.

That fixed it for me...

Comment: Just tried it and it worked for me too.

Comment: I tried before tonight, then did again and saw why I didnt uninstall it-- asepsisctl uninstall doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks, re-install than asepsisctl uninstall did the trick!

Comment: I don't have asepsis. Apparently a bug report has been filed: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4143805?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me on 10.8.2 and just logging out then back in fixed it.