# "DYLD_" terminal error?

Tags: macos, terminal

So, I've done some searching.. and still haven't found a solution for this. I'm not even sure what has caused it. There are no DYLD_ or LD_ flags being set *at all*, but I always see this when I open the terminal up.

```
dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/usr/bin/login) is setuid or setgid
```

Would definitely appreciate help with this.

Comment: 1. Were one of the answers on another question 'repair disk permissions' from disk utility? 2. Open Terminal (Applications > Utilities) and run: `ls -laFh /usr/bin/login`, paste the output into a comment. For reference, mine is: `-r-sr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    67K Sep 19 17:01 /usr/bin/login*`

Comment: Yeah. I ran the disk permissions repair earlier, but to no avail. Permissions are exactly the same as your's.

Comment: Why not list what you tried that didn't work? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58228/

Comment: Can't we continue the discussion in http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58228/ and close this one? It doesn't add additional value and just confuses everybody.

Comment: NOTE: Repairing disk permissions is highly unlikely to help. The message occurs because /usr/bin/login is necessarily setuid root. Barring a bug, this really does indicate that some DYLD_* environment variable is set somewhere that's causing it to be set before /usr/bin/login is invoked by Terminal to create a new terminal session.

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently it was the new Umbrella client by OpenDNS causing this error. I uninstalled it and continued to get this error until I restarted, which was making me think that it was something other than this client. However, after some testing.. it's confirmed that it's this client that's causing it.

So, yeah.. This definitely wasn't a duplicate or related to any of the duplicates that have been posted in the comments in the question.

Comment: The usual reason in a situation like this is an application setting DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH or DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH (or DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH or DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH) in order to find frameworks/libraries that are stored in the application's bundle, or installed in a custom location for its use. See the dyld(1) man page for information about the environment variables it supports and what they do: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html